# Testnet can hash problem be reduced

Tags: testnet, bitcoin.conf

I have a question concerning setting up a testnet.
I am setting up a testnet. I tried to get some testnet coin be I did not a success.
But anyway is it possible to reduces the probability of getting a coin on a test net without recompiling the bitcoin source.
I remember in 2011 it was relatively easy to get coins for test.

Can you set a parameter in the bitcoin.conf to reduces the hash probability

Best
Carsten

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [regtest](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#regtest-mode). It lets you generate as many blocks as you want on a private network.